# Can we send cardholder name in braintree API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, braintree

I have implemented braintree SDK for payment. Need to know is there any way we can send cardholder name too.

//

BTClientCardRequest  *request  =  [BTClientCardRequest new];

```
         request.number = @"1232123212321232";
         request.expirationMonth = @"11";
         request.expirationYear = @"2012";
```

is there any field to add cardholder name also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no field like cardholder name for now. We can't send.
but we can save cardholder name in our own server against the payment.nonce we generated for the user from braintree

Answer (score 0):

You can send in **additionalParameters** parameter if you want to send.

Comment: but how ? if you check braintree SDK , there is no provision to that parameter. they have only CVV, postalcode, number , expiry date and month

Comment: When creating the nonce you can pass in the cardholder name in additionalParameters, as Imran stated. Alternatively, you can save the cardholder name when you create the customer or payment method. All methods are equal from a PCI standpoint.
[Customer Create](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create)
[Payment Method Create](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create)